# javafx tableview change the focus of a textfield

Tags: javafx, tableview, focus, textfield

how can I move the focus of a textfield to the below textfield pressing ENTER, I dont want to change the textfield to read only. I tried to get the current focus but the cell is not focused only in the textfield but I dont know how to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `yourNextTextField.requestFocus()` in `yourCurrentTextField.setOnAction()`.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication200 extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        TextField textField1 = new TextField();
        TextField textField2 = new TextField();
        TextField textField3 = new TextField();

        textField1.setOnAction((event) -> {
            //Do some stuff

            textField2.requestFocus();
        });

        textField2.setOnAction((event) -> {
            //Do some stuff

            textField3.requestFocus();
        });

        textField3.setOnAction((event) -> {
            //Do some stuff

            textField1.requestFocus();
        });
        Parent root = new VBox(textField1, textField2, textField3);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the textfield is inside of a cell. For example, I fill the textfield located in the cell (0,0), I press enter and the focus moves to the textfield located in the cell (1,0)

Comment: ???  Inside what kind of cell. Don't you think this information should have been shared when crafting the question? You need to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry for my bref question. I will try to kraft future question, I add the class with the contains of the cell. Later I will try to create an example.